# change textbox value in client side and read it in server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, textbox, updatepanel

I have some textbox and I change the value of this textboxes in clientside (javascript) ,value was changed but when I read in server side after postback actually value not changed. my textbox isn't read only or disable.
notice that I use updatepanel and my postbacks is async.any idea to solve this issue?

**update**
I use [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js) jquery to support placeholder in ie,but it cause value of my textboxes equal to placeholder value, and this conflict when my postback is async. for solving this problem I use below jquery code:

```
function EndRequestPostBackForUpdateControls() {
//*****************************For place holder support in ie******************************
if (runPlaceHolder != 0) {
    //alert('end');
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();


    var $inputs = $('.placeholder');
    $inputs.each(function () {

        var $replacement;
        var input = this;
        var $input = $(input);
        var id = this.id;
        if (input.value == '') {
            if (input.type == 'password') {
                if (!$input.data('placeholder-textinput')) {
                    try {
                        $replacement = $input.clone().attr({ 'type': 'text' });
                    } catch (e) {
                        $replacement = $('<input>').attr($.extend(args(this), { 'type': 'text' }));
                    }
                    $replacement
                    .removeAttr('name')
                    .data({
                        'placeholder-password': $input,
                        'placeholder-id': id
                    })
                    .bind('focus.placeholder', clearPlaceholder);
                    $input
                    .data({
                        'placeholder-textinput': $replacement,
                        'placeholder-id': id
                    })
                    .before($replacement);
                }
                $input = $input.removeAttr('id').hide().prev().attr('id', id).show();
                // Note: `$input[0] != input` now!
            }
            $input.addClass('placeholder');
            $input[0].value = $input.attr('placeholder');
        } else {
            $input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    });
}}
function safeActiveElement() {
// Avoid IE9 `document.activeElement` of death
// https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/pull/99
try {
    return document.activeElement;
} catch (err) { }}

function BeginRequestPostBackForUpdateControls() {
//*****************************For place holder support in ie******************************
if (runPlaceHolder != 0) {
    // Clear the placeholder values so they don't get submitted
    var $inputs = $('.placeholder').each(function () {
        var input = this;
        var $input = $(input);
        if (input.value == $input.attr('placeholder') && $input.hasClass('placeholder')) {
            if ($input.data('placeholder-password')) {

                $input = $input.hide().next().show().attr('id', $input.removeAttr('id').data('placeholder-id'));
                // If `clearPlaceholder` was called from `$.valHooks.input.set`
                if (event === true) {
                    return $input[0].value = value;
                }
                $input.focus();
            } else {
                alert($(this)[0].value);
                $(this)[0].value = '';
                alert($(this)[0].value);
                $input.removeClass('placeholder');
                input == safeActiveElement() && input.select();
            }
        }
    });
}}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestPostBackForUpdateControls);

    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestPostBackForUpdateControls);

});
```

I use this code to clear my textbox value before sending to server in add_beginRequest,and set value in add_endRequest (for placeholder in ie).
can anyone help solve this problem? thank you.

Comment: what is your javqscript code?

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake I add javascript code in my question

Answer (score 3):

You changed the `value` of `TextBox` with `javascript` and the respective `ViewState` is not updated. You can use `hidden` field to store the value in javascript and get it in code behind.

*Html*

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
document.getElementById("hdn").value = "your value";
```

*Code behind*

```
string hdnValue = hdn.Value;
```

Comment: all of my textbox has this problem.this problem is caused only in IE because I use jquery.placeholder ,I can't use hf because I have a lot of textbox with this problem :(

Comment: I add my javascript code in question,can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden field to store the value, and retrieve it on the server side.

Comment: all of my textbox has this problem.this problem is caused only in IE because I use jquery.placeholder ,I can't use hf because I have a lot of textbox with this problem :(

Comment: I add my javascript code in question,can you help me?